# How to find the related record that is related to my search field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch I want to find the related record that is relevant to my search field like stackoverflow related question suggestion.That means, Matches search result which are near one another.

For example I search  "Men's Shoe"  from the following data

1. "Men's Shoe"
2. "Girl's Shoe"
3. "Men's Shoe black color"
4. "Women's Shoe"
5. "Women's Shoe pink color"
6. "Women's Shoe  red color"
7. "Boy's Shoe"
8. "Men's Shoe gray color"
9. "Men's Shoe white color"
10. "Men's Shoe green color"
11. "Men's footwear"

Then how I can get more related tuple with search item "Men's Shoe" ? And how can I get data related to synonym also ie. Men's footware.

## Bulk Insert in Kibana

```
POST /atomap/product/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"name": "Girl's Shoe"}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"name": "Men's Shoe"}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"name": "Women's Shoe"}
{"index":{"_id":"4"}}       
{"name": "Women's Shoe pink color"}
{"index":{"_id":"5"}}
{"name": "Women's Shoe red color"}
{"index":{"_id":"6"}}
{"name": "Boy's Shoe"}
{"index":{"_id":"7"}}
{"name": "Men's Shoe red color"}
{"index":{"_id":"8"}}
{"name": "Men's Shoe white color"}
{"index":{"_id":"9"}}
{"name": "Men's Shoe green color"}
{"index":{"_id":"10"}}
{"name": "Men's Shoe gray color"}
{"index":{"_id":"11"}}
{"name": "Men's footwear"}
```

## I have tried with `more like this` query:

```
GET /atomap/product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
        "like": "Men's shoe",
        "min_term_freq": 1,
        "min_doc_freq": 1
     }
   }
}
```

My question is **How can I search for related words?** As [More Like This Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) can not find "Men's Footwear" in top when I search "Men's Shoe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create synonyms and field mapping:**

```
PUT /atomap
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym", 
          "synonyms": [ 
            "shoe,footwear",
            "color,colour"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter" 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings":{

  "product" : {
     "properties" : {
        "name" : {
           "type" : "string",
           "analyzer" : "my_synonyms"
        }
     }
  }

  }
}
```

**Then insert all data, after that run the following query:**

```
POST /myshop/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "name",
            "query": "Men's shoe",
            "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your query (against the index `atomap` instead of `my_test`)

```
GET /atomap/product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
        "like": "Men's shoe",
        "min_term_freq": 1,
        "min_doc_freq": 1
     }
   }
}
```

I get `Men's footwear` as the 4th result with score 0.62191015. Tested on Elasticsearch 5.2.

PS: Bonus points for providing the test data and query. Otherwise there would be no chance to reproduce this.

Comment: It was my mistake of index name. But I want `Men's Footwear` in 3rd position ie. before `Women's Shoe`